# How to apply Cloudfront to S3 existing Bucket with signed URL

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, pre-signed-url

I have S3 Bucket and which is already configured with KMS encryption and Signed URL features.

As I want to add the Cloudfront to restrict the s3 URLs and apply the signed URL.
Do I need to remove the existing S3 signed URL features from S3 or what?
Can someone provide the proper approaches?

Answer (score 0):

There is no option in S3 console for you to toggle on/off for Signed URL.

Signed URL is a mechanism to share private objects in S3 buckets, usually provided by either CLI, API or AWS SDK. Since the objects are private, S3 requires valid credentials to allow external users to access, in this case a pair of temporary access key and secret.

This feature is independent of Cloudfront Signed URL. You can have both working at the same time.

The reason why people want Cloudfront Signed URL is often due to the ability to provide custom domain for accessing S3 object, which can't be done with S3 signed URL.

With S3 Signed URL, the result URL has S3 domain, s3.amazonaws.com

With Cloudfront Signed URL, you can point it to your own domain, e.g: files.example.com

Refs:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html

Answer (score 0):

umm, I understand they are really the same thing, just that with CloudFront you also can use cookie signing instead of URL signing and that by using a specific key pair in cloudfront the model is more advanced